# Graph with 3d view in javascript and sencha ext js

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to draw a 3D chart look like this.. [3D Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcopB.png)
 I want to do it in javascript or sencha.. i have no idea where to start from.. Please give me some idea..

EDITED: Here i wanted to pass the values of the graph as JSON

Comment: Start from googling "**web gl chart**", it have plenty of results like this https://code.google.com/p/webgl-surface-plot/ .

Comment: Thats really nice.. thanks.. where can i download the code completely like a package or project..

Comment: This particular project is open source (like all google code projects), and you can download it from downloads section there. Also check jsfiddle link there.

Comment: Thanks setec.. But its very difficult to understand..

Answer (score 0):

You can create this type of chart easily using [Orson Charts for HTML5](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/web/index.html).

Disclosure: I am the developer of this library.

Comment: yes .. its nice.. but to draw a chart it needs licence.its lots of money... right? but its not possible for me ..

Comment: There is a free edition that you can use if you don't mind the copyright notice and URL that it places on the chart.  If you buy a license (which sounds like it is not an option for you), you can have charts without this annotation.